# Macbook Air 2017 won't charge

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, magsafe

I have the MacBook Air 2017 and until today it was working fine. Now, when I plug in the Mag Safe connector the light doesn't turn on nor does the computer detect that I've plugged the cable in.

I've tried resetting the SMC using different sockets and cleaning out the ports. I've also noticed that when plugged into certain outlets I can feel an electric "charge" on the cable and MacBook body.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: When you write: _"...the cable is electric so is the metal body of the laptop..."_ do you mean you are feeling an electrical shock when you touch the cable or the laptop case?

Comment: It's normal to feel a very slight buzzing sensation from a plugged-in device, but anything more severe than that suggests an electrical fault with either your adapter or (more seriously) your house wiring. First of all can you take your MacBook somewhere (Apple Store, repair shop, friend etc) where you can test it with another adapter?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes thats exactly what I feel

Comment: @nekomatic ill try that now

Answer (score 1):

If this happened just recently as you describe, you may have an electrical issue; especially if it's happening only on certain electrical outlets.

What this sounds like is that something on your [DC-in board](http://radnex.us/mba-dc-in-magsafe) has been shorted to ground (the whole case is grounded). The fix would be to simply replace this board.

[image]

[iFixit.com has a guide on how to replace it](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+11-Inch+Mid+2011+I-O+Board+Replacement/6310).  It's rated as difficult because you have to remove the battery, so if this is not your cup of tea, it's best that you take it in for service.

However, before doing so, I would get the electrical system in your home/office (where ever you're having the problem) checked out because if that's the problem, you'll be doing this fix all over again.  If that's not an option, plug into a high quality surge protector or UPS (APC and CyberPower are two brands I recommend)

Comment: I don't know where the OP is located, but it's possible that the Mac in question is still under warranty.